# How to make the output appear in github using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using Github to create a portfolio. I wrote some code in Google Colab and uploaded it to Github. But I can't see the output. I'd like to see the output appear, so the person who sees my portfolio would understand what I have done.

Is there any way to show the output in github?

Colab:
[image]

Github:

[image]

Comment: Is your Github site public? You can try the Jupyter ecosystem's supported notebook viewer [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/). You go there and put in your GitHub repo or gist link & you'll get a page with it rendered. nbviewer renders things much better than GitHub's default viewer. While GitHub's viewer has much improved of late, nbviewer remains the go-to site for this purpose and to share rendered links. GitHub's renderer is best thought of as being there to provide some basic insight & for those actively using GitHub. nbviewer is more full-featured & meant for sharing with non-GitHub users.

Comment: @Wayne that work perfectly and it's easy. Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to make it a proper answer since others might end up here given the title of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/), provided by the Jupyter community, offers many types of rich output rendering and interactivity for previously run notebooks.

nbviewer has several full-featured abilities GitHub doesn't and presents it in a nice way that's not overwhelming for those not as tech savvy as GitHub users. You can point it at any GitHub or gist, or even where the notebook code is online at a URL. The link to the view can be shared with others.

I like to think of the Github notebook viewer as a quick preview.

---

Also if you are working more on a mobile devices you may be interested in a parallel tech at [nbsanity.com](https://nbsanity.com/). (Source code at https://github.com/hamelsmu/nbsanity .)

> "I WAS SO FRUSTRATED with the way @github renders Jupyter Notebooks, esp on mobile (You cannot horizontal scroll code, even with nbviewer). It's different than nbviewer because it uses
> @quarto_pub as the renderer, which has a more sane way of showing notebooks on different platforms.The upshot is, it will also respect all the quarto directives if that happens to be in your notebook" - Source:
> Hamel Husain ([here](https://twitter.com/HamelHusain/status/1716266805097070712) and [here](https://twitter.com/HamelHusain/status/1716269213890031905))

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Thank you, @Wayne. Anyway, when GitHub will support the render like nbviewer?

Comment: @dudung I have no idea. Or if they ever would. Adding more options and abilities adds more to maintain or more for others to exploit. Plus there's other things they need to insure it doesn't break.